# How to parse this code?

Tags: python, json, parsing, web, python-requests

I'm stuck since this morning on how to get the 'Tier' of this json answer from [here](https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.5/league/by-summoner/266302,29338851,44112476,24693443,42900539,32556822,25575027,27677126,24648065,19083702/entry?api_key=2c0543ab-aeca-476d-8276-a5c23748898c). I have been trying this:

```
url = #given
response = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(response.text)

for ids in data:
    print(ids['tier'])
```

And it keeps telling me this : `print(ids['tier']) TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: `ids` is not a dictionary, it's a string.

Comment: Try using a JSON viewer/beautifer, such as this one http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer to help you visualize the structure in your JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the following:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.5/league/by-summoner/266302,29338851,44112476,24693443,42900539,32556822,25575027,27677126,24648065,19083702/entry?api_key=2c0543ab-aeca-476d-8276-a5c23748898c'
response = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(response.text)

for ids in data:
    print(data[ids][0]['tier'])
```

**Output**

```
PLATINUM
SILVER
SILVER
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `ids` as if it's a `dictionary`, but the `TypeError` you are getting says it's a `String`.